# Как работать с дополнением morozovsk/yii2-websocket

Tags: yii2

Пытаюсь разобраться с работой Websocet казалось нашел нормальное решение и скачал [дополнения](https://github.com/morozovsk/yii2-websocket) сделал все по инструкции вроде за исключением поместил класс Chat3WebsocketDaemonHandler в папку console/models и в конфиге console/config/main.php

```
'websocket' => [
            'class' => 'morozovsk\yii2websocket\Connection',
            'servers' => [
                'chat3' => [
                    'class' => 'console\models\Chat3WebsocketDaemonHandler',
                    'pid' => '/tmp/websocket_chat.pid',
                    'websocket' => 'tcp://127.0.0.1:8004',
                    'localsocket' => 'tcp://127.0.0.1:8010',
                    //'master' => 'tcp://127.0.0.1:8020',
                    //'eventDriver' => 'event'
                ]
            ],
        ],
```

сам этот класс взял у вас от [сюда](https://github.com/morozovsk/websocket/wiki)  но чутка видоизменил на такой

```
<?php
namespace console\models;
class Chat3WebsocketDaemonHandler extends \morozovsk\websocket\Daemon
{
    protected function onOpen($connectionId, $info) {
        //call when new client connect to server
        $message ="yes";
    }

    protected function onClose($connectionId) {
        //call when existing client close connection
    }

    protected function onMessage($connectionId, $data, $type) {
        //call when new message from existing client

        $message = "user #{$connectionId}: $data";

        //send message to all client
        foreach ($this->clients as $clientId => $client) {
            $this->sendToClient($clientId, $message);
        }
    }
}
```

теперь пытаюсь запустить так ./yii websocket/start chat3 и реакция не то что бы нулевая но вот такая [реакция](https://www.dropbox.com/s/1lzlk88k07a8jto/%D0%92%D1%8B%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_001.png?dl=0)

а если я начинаю писать то вот [так](https://www.dropbox.com/s/vqacbr5l76ykntn/%D0%92%D1%8B%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_002.png?dl=0) 
 я понимаю что этот чат должен не так работать может подскажите где я чего на тупил

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Запускайте чат через  `nohup yii websocket/start chat3 &`
Так у вас не будет повисать процесс и вебсокет сервер будет запущенным. Но есть нюанс, если не юзать постоянно чат, сервер отвалится. Так что тут нужно будет придумать самому, может по интервалу делать ping => pong так сказать.

Comment: это под линукс так, на убунте (mint) nohup стоял изначально, если у вас нет то установите, под убунту так:  `apt-get install nohup`